# Show $f$ is continuous at a point $a \in [0,1]$, iff $a$ is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $r_1, r_2,.... $ be an enumeration of the set of rationals on the real line. For each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, let us put $f(x) = \sum_{n;r_n\leq x} \dfrac{1}{2^n} $ . Show $f$ is continuous at a point $a\in [0,1]$, iff $a$ is irrational.

for irrational points the terms of the series are infinite and for rational points the terms are finite and the sums are finite. So how do I choose an $\epsilon$ to prove that $f$ is not continuous at $a\in \mathbb{Q}$?
Any hints?

Comment: I don't know then, I found it in a problem set.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is the domain and I added a full stop there. I think it make sense now

Comment: @uniquesolution  I intepret that statement as:  If $a \in (0,1)$ then $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $a$ is irrational".  I'd say that what is written is ungrammatical and contains a typo but it is salvageable.  (If my interpretation is correct,, that is, ... I don't want to make any unwarranted assumptions.)

Comment: "for irrational points the terms of a series are infinite and for rational points the terms are finite and the sums are finite"  I don't think that is true  for any $x \in (0,1)$ whether $x$ is rational or irrational there are any infinite number or $r_n < x$ and and infinite number of $r_m > x$.  The only difference is if $x$ is rational then there is an $r_n = x$ but there isn't if $x$ is irrational.  Hint: (I think) If $x$ is rational then for every $\epsilon$, then $r_n=x$ and $n$ in the index.  If $x$ is irrational the you can force all the indexes to be high.

Comment: "for rational x once it reaches x the index stops. Right?"  No.  if $r_m = q$ then you *don't* stop.  There will be $n > m$ so that $r_n < r_m = q$.  As there are infinitely many rationals less than $q$ there are infinitely many $r_n < q$ and infinitely many of the those $n$ will be greater than $m$.

Comment: @fleablood Oh!! yeah, I'll try

Comment: @fleablood can you please elaborate on "If x is rational then for every ϵ, then $r_n=x$ and n in the index." this n won't affect the sum, I can't find any contradiction

Comment: Try showing that if $x$ is rational, $x = r_k$, then $$f(x) - \lim_{\substack{ y \to x \\ y < x}} f(y) = \frac{1}{2^k}\,.$$

Comment: Claim:  If you have a point $x$, and a very large natural natural number $N$, you can find an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for all the rationals $q=r_n$ (other than $x$) so that $0 < |x-q|< \epsilon$ that the index of $q = r_n$, that is $n$, will be that $n > N$....
Pf:  Let $\epsilon = \min(|x - r_k|: k \le N, r_k \ne x)$......  Can you use that?

Comment: See also: [Construct a monotone function which has countably many discontinuities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69317) and [Prove $f$ is discontinuous on $r_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1274475)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x < y$ then if $D_x= \{m| r_m \le x\}$ and $D_y = \{m|r_m\le y\}$ then $D_x \subset D_y$.  And as there is rational $q$ so that $x < q < y$ and there is a $k$ so that $q = r_k$ so $k\in D_y$ but $k\not \in D_x$, $D_x$ is a  *proper* subset of $D_y$. So $f(x) =\sum_{m\in D_x}\frac 1{2^m} <\sum_{m\in D_y}\frac 1{2^m} = f(y)$.

Now $q= r_k$ is rational then for all $x < r_k$ then $k \not \in D_x\subsetneq D_q$ but $k \in D_q$ so $f(x) = \sum_{m\in D_x} f(x) \le \sum_{m\in D_q;m\ne k} \frac 1{2^m} < \sum_{m\in D_q;m\ne k} \frac 1{2^m}+\frac 1{2^k} =\sum_{m\in D_q}\frac 1{2^m} =f(q)$.  So $|f(q) - f(x)| \ge \frac 1{2^k}$.  So $f$ can not be continuous at any rational $q$.

Now suppose $x$ is irrational and let $D_x = \{m| r_m \le x\}$.

Now for any $\epsilon > 0$ then let $\frac 1{2^w} < \epsilon$.  $\frac 1{2^w} = \sum_{j> w} \frac 1{2^j}$.

Now let $\delta = \min_{m=1}^w(|x-r_m|)$.

Now the only rationals in the interval $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ can only have indexes larger that $w$ (because if $q = r_k$ and $k \le w$ then $|x-r_k| \ge \delta$ by the way we defined $\delta$).

Now if $|x-y| < \delta$ then only  the elements in $D_y$ that are not in $D_x$ (if $y > x$) or the elements of $D_x$ not in $D_y$ (if $x > y$) are the indexes of rationals in the interval so the only elments of $D_y$ not in $D_x$ (or vice versa) are indexes larger than $w$.

So $|f(x) - f(y)| \le \sum_{j>w} \frac 1{2^j} = \frac 1{2^w} < \epsilon$.

So $f$ is continuous at $x$.